# System Verilog seq.ended or seq.triggered

Tags: system-verilog

Some verification tools support the following System Verilog code:

```
wire s = seq.ended;
```

Where seq is an SVA sequence. Other tools do not support this code. Is this "standard SV"?

If not, what would be an equivalent way to define such a wire in "standard SV"?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the IEEE Std 1800-2005, `ended` is used inside an assertion, property, or another sequence (§ 17.7.10, ex `@(posedge clk) reset ##1 inst ##1 my_seq.ended`). `triggered` is is the equivalent to `ended` and is allowed outside of an assertion (§ 10.11, ex `wait(my_seq.triggered)`).

`ended` has been depreciated in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) as mentioned in § C.2.3:

> IEEE Std 1800-2005 17.7.3 required using the sequence method `ended` in
>   sequence expressions and the sequence method `triggered` in other
>   contexts. Since these two constructs have the same meaning but
>   mutually exclusive usage contexts, in this version of the standard,
>   the triggered method is allowed to be used in sequence expressions,
>   and the usage of `ended` is deprecated and does not appear in this
>   version of the standard.

Few if any simulators are 1800-2012 complaint, so follow with 1800-2005 for now.